# sql repeating union all

Tags: sql, sql-server

For school I have a datetime view with a list containing dates from 1-1-2000 till 31-12-2999. Now i want to create a view where i add holidays to this table using a case when. Some holidays are on the same day and that's why I need to use a union all. This get the following code:

```
select *
from (
Select date as d,
                case
                --  New Years Day
                    when date_trunc('year',d) = d then 'NH - New Years Day'
               else NULL
                end as holiday_name
from dim_date t
union all
Select date as d,
                case
               --  Christmas Break School
                    when d between '2020-12-19' and '2021-01-03' then 'Christmas Break School'
                    when d between '2021-12-25' and '2021-01-09' then 'Christmas Break School'
                    else NULL
                end as holiday_name
from dim_date t
union all
Select date as d,
                case
               --  Carnaval
                    when d between '2021-02-11' and '2021-02-16' then 'Carnaval'
                    else NULL
                end as holiday_name
from dim_date t
) as x
where 1+1 = 2 
and x.holiday_name is not null
```

This makes it that i get a row for new years day and also for christmas break school.
THE PROBLEM: I need to keep repeating for every holiday the following part makeing it  very long

```
Select date as d,
                case
               --  Carnaval
                    when d between '2021-02-11' and '2021-02-16' then 'Carnaval'
                    else NULL
                end as holiday_name
from dim_date t
```

This is going make the query very long because i have list of over ~50 holidays. Is there any way to shorten this?

Comment: Using a `UNION ALL` here certainly feels like you have chosen the wrong path for your solution here. Why not simply have another table with the holiday dates, and then `(LEFT) JOIN` to that that from your `dim_date` table?

Comment: Why do you look at New Years for all years but only the school break for one year?

Comment: Because the holidays can't be in a table so they are at the cast mentioned first time. The school break shuffels year to year

Comment: *"Because the holidays can't be in a table"* why not? That'#s the logical place to store data. Not in a bunch of `CASE` expressions, which will never scale well.

Comment: You have a table of date called dim_date and you have a list of approx 50 holidays and you'd like to relate them to each other.  That's what relational databases are good at.  If you insist no holiday table is possible (why?) it still makes sense to organize the code whereby the holidays are represented in a virtual table (or common table expression).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the data were organized into virtual (or physical) table something like this could simplify the creation and execution of your queries

```
;with
dim_date_cte([date]) as (
    select cast('20000101' as date) union all
    select '20000102' union all
    select '20000103' union all
    select '20000104' union all
    select '20000105'),
holidays_cte(start_dt, end_dt, holiday_name) as (
    select '20000101', '20000101', 'New Year'
    union all
    select '20000103', '20000104', 'Jan 3-4 Holdiay')
select dc.[date], hc.holiday_name
from dim_date_cte dc
     left join holidays_cte hc on dc.[date] between hc.start_dt and hc.end_dt;
```

Output

```
date        holiday_name
2000-01-01  New Year
2000-01-02  NULL
2000-01-03  Jan 3-4 Holdiay
2000-01-04  Jan 3-4 Holdiay
2000-01-05  NULL
```